# How do I use BirdNet without getting an error?

Tags: birdnet, python

BirdNet is very new to me and I can't really find a guide online. I've installed it, and I've done the 'pip3 install pywebview gradio' to use the GUI version. Every time I've uploaded a recording and clicked analyze I've either gotten an error after a few seconds or had it run for hours without stopping. When I get the error, after I hit analyze it shows queue 1/1 then a time counter then error. When I get it going on forever it's just the time counter increasing.

The files I've uploaded have been flac and have been 3-15 minutes long. I tried using the filters and leaving the filters as is. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Welcome @user3253741! It looks like you figured out your issue in your comment below, which is great. Would you mind editing your question to add a bit more detail on the type of error message you were getting, so that this may help others in the future?

Comment: Sadly there was no error message it just says "ERROR" in the analyze box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following procedure (as by instructions) on windows

```
Opened powershell

conda create -n birdnet python=3.11
conda activate birdnet
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install librosa resampy
pip install tensorflow
pip install pywebview gradio

downloaded birdnet-analyzer from github, extracted folder from zip 

cd downloads\birdnet-analyzer-main
python gui.py

selected as input and output folder the birdnet-analyzer-main\example

selected the species_list.txt in example folder

pressed start Analysis
```

program was running fine using the soundscape.wav file in example folder.

Not sure what you did wrong, as the info you provided does not allow a more detailed diagnosis.

BTW, there is a standalone compiled birdnet-analyzer with an exe file that immediately shows you the gui

Comment: Hey thanks it looks like it just doesn't work with flac and does with wav

Answer (score 0):

..............................................................................

Comment: PS : sorry, I was thinking of starting a new post...

Comment: you can delete your own answer (I guess)

Comment: Hum, i think not...